# Drag & Drop - DataTransfer object

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, drag

I'm building a simple drag n' drop uploader and I'm wondering why I can't see the file(s) I drop when I `console.log(e)` (DragEvent) and look at the `DragEvent.dataTransfer.files` it shows up empty, but... if I `console.log(e.dataTransfer.files)` it will show the dropped file(s).

//CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
function init(){
    var dropbox = document.getElementById('dropbox');
    dropbox.addEventListener('dragover', drag.over);
    dropbox.addEventListener('drop', drag.drop);
}
var drag = {
    "over": function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    },
    "drop": function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e); //NO FILES SHOWN
        console.log(e.dataTransfer.files); //FILES in FileList Object
    }   
};  
</script>
<style>
body{
    margin: 0 !important;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#dropbox{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    align-self: center;
    background-color: #0089C4;
    border-radius: .3em;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dropbox"></div>    
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: At the time you click at object in console it may have passed through multiple functions changing its properties. So why would you expect it to be the same? If you need it later, you can freeze it, clone or copy value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The **drag data store** has different modes depending on when you access it:

- On `dragstart` event it's on **read/write** mode.
- On `drop` event, it's in **read only** mode.
- And on all other events, it's in **protected** mode.

  **Protected** mode is defined this way:

> Protected mode
>
> For all other events. The formats and kinds in the drag data store
>   list of items representing dragged data can be enumerated, but the
>   data itself is unavailable and no new data can be added.

See here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-drag-data-store

That means that when you access the `dataTransfer` object in your console, which is not on `drop` or `dragstart` event, it's in **protected** mode, preventing you from accessing the data.

You can view the `fileList` because you log the `fileList` on `drop` event when `dataTransfer` is readable. But if you log `e.dataTransfer` or `e`, you won't be able to access any data.

You can test here, even on `dragover` you can't access what's in `dataTransfer`:

```js
document.querySelector('#droppable').ondragover = function(e) {
  console.log('on dragover files are', e.dataTransfer.files)
  e.preventDefault();
}

document.querySelector('#droppable').ondrop = function(e) {
  console.log('on drop files are', e.dataTransfer.files)
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<div id=droppable>Drop a file</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I finally found an explanation for why in IE `e.dataTransfer.files` is always empty when I try to use it in a `dragover` or `dragenter` event handler — it's not actually empty, it's just protected.