# Simple Drag and Drop File

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I am trying to get the file object on the drop but I'm not clear on what's going on.

```
$(".file-field").on('dragover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('dragover');
});
$(".file-field").on('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.dataTransfer = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    console.log('e = ', e.dataTransfer);
    console.log('drop');
});
$(".file-field").on('dragleave', function(e) {
    console.log('dragleave');
});
```

This is the output from dataTransfer:

> e = DataTransfer {dropEffect: "none", effectAllowed: "all", items:
>   DataTransferItemList, types: Array(1), files: FileList} dropEffect :
>   "none" effectAllowed : "all" files : FileList {length: 0} items :
>   DataTransferItemList {length: 0} types : []
>   **proto** : DataTransfer

I was expecting to find some data on the file I dropped.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe the jQueryUI example might help: https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager

Comment: Your code is fine, it's just the DataTransfer object is protected and the console won't be able to read its data. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420306/drag-drop-datatransfer-object

Comment: @AarónBC.Thank you helped a lot